# Excel VBA - Fetch Data from Website

Tags: excel, vba

I am usng followng approach **to download tabular data from a site**. But it's taking approx 1.5 seconds for each loop iteration. I need to speed it up. Any suggestion(s) please?

```
Sub GetData_Sai()
    Dim htm As Object
    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Row = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    For p = Range("F1") To Range("F1") + 200
        Debug.Print p
        Set htm = CreateObject("htmlFile")
        With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
            .Open "GET", <site_url_goes_here>, False
            .send
            htm.body.innerhtml = .responsetext
        End With

        With htm.getelementbyid("item")
            Sheet2.Cells(Row, 4).Value = p
            For x = 1 To .Rows.Length - 1
                For y = 0 To .Rows(x).Cells.Length - 1
                    Sheet2.Cells(Row, y + 1).Value = .Rows(x).Cells(y).innertext
                Next y
                Row = Row + 1
            Next x
        End With
        Set htm = Nothing

        If p Mod 10 = 0 Then ThisWorkbook.Save
    Next

    Range("F1") = p

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: If you debug it, which part is taking the most time?

Comment: Kindly provide link for the site you want to fetch data. The approach differs according to site.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: The GET request part. Statement: .Open "GET", <site_url_goes_here>, False

Comment: @Santosh: It's from [here](http://www.datarabia.com/biz/searchOrgs.do?id=0&sectorid=0&more=1&submit=Search&orgname=&listid=&type=1&d-49489-p=3455)

Comment: Have you considered using Stephen Bullen's PerfMon to determine the bottleneck?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider opening the MSXML2.XMLHTTP object only once and then calling `Open` and `Send` within each loop iteration.  You can store it in a variable before you start the loop.  I am sure that most of the time is being spent creating the object and not in the actual `Open` call.  Based on the way you are calling it in your code above, you create a new object in each loop iteration.